# How to merge overlapped detections for each detected object?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, object-detection

I developed a software for testing object detection using HOG descriptor.

- I used a window scanning method in order to detect instances of target object classes.
- The image is examined several times using scanning windows of different sizes in order to detect objects with different sizes (multiscale detection). In this way, each object may be detected multiple times.

The presence of overlapping detections (multiple bounding box of different positions and sizes) for each object requires a procedure to combine them into a single bounding box that includes all the detections related to the same object. How to merge multiple detections for each object?

Comment: what do you mean by merge? Are these the same Rect object at different times or different objects?

Comment: @Chubsdad: How to combine overlapping detections into a single detection?

Comment: So, you just want to know that you have already processed a 'Rectangle' and skip further detection of 'Rectangles'?

Comment: @Chubsdad: No... I improved my question to better describe my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using the [OpenCV groupRectangles function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles), which clusters rectangles with similar sizes and locations according to a similarity parameter. Although, I believe this function may already be being used within the [HOG detectMultiScale function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor-detectmultiscale) according to the parameter `group_threshold`:

```
void gpu::HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale(
    const GpuMat& img,
    vector<Rect>& found_locations,
    double hit_threshold=0,
    Size win_stride=Size(),
    Size padding=Size(),
    double scale0=1.05,
    int group_threshold=2
)
```

Of course you will have to try and tune the similarity criterion to suit your needs.

Comment: What is the OpenCV library where this function is defined?

Comment: The function [groupRectangles](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles) is defined in objdetect.hpp, in the module objdetect. (At least that's where it is in OpenCV2.4.4).